# ng-audio not working well on chrome with time track

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, audio

I am working with [ng-audio](https://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/docs) library for angularJS, it works nice. I can play the audio, or stop it, but when I move the audio forward, it starts again, in others words, the time track doesn't work.

This is my HTML:

```
<div>
  <audio ng-show="false" controls id="myAudio">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
  </audio>
  <div ng-audio-control source="audio_url.wav">
</div>
```

I know for this feature the library use a function named: `currentTime`, but if I do:

```
$scope.audio.currentTime = 15;
```

When I get `$scope.audio.currentTime` it says `0`.

Now comes the odd part. When I refresh the page (Just a simple F5), the audio works 100% well, and it allows me to play with the time-track normally. Any thoughts?

Comment: a link is already added @georgeawg, please look at the first line of the question

Comment: The symptoms match what happens subsequent to an `unbind()`.